# how to call the function in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(scriptPath)
ENG_RequestDataFile = scriptPath + "\ENG_RequestData.json"
DEU_RequestDataFile = scriptPath + "\DEU_RequestData.json"
LNG = ('ENG', 'DEU')
def ENG_Request():
    try:
        with open(ENG_RequestDataFile) as json_file:   
                #print json_file
                JSON_ENGData = json.load(json_file)
                print JSON_ENGData      
    except:
        print ("[ERROR] Cannot open the ENG JSON file")

def DEU_Request():
    try:
        with open(DEU_RequestDataFile) as json_file:    
            JSON_DEUData = json.load(json_file)
            print JSON_DEUData

    except:
        print ("[ERROR] Cannot open the DEU JSON file")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if (LNG[0] == 'ENG'):
        print LNG[0]
        ENG_Request()

    elif (LNG[1] == 'DEU'):
        DEU_Request()
    else:
        print "NO More Languages"
```

The above code is opening the JSON file but before that I am comparing the two languages as ENG and DEU. If it is ENG then call specific function as above and if it is DEU then call some other specific function. But I am not able to call the specific function form the main function. can someone tell me what is the mistake ?

Comment: You're not calling them. Calling the function = `ENG_Request()`

Comment: sorry !! I forgot to add that in my code. but I am getting the error as print "NO More Languages". it is not calling any function

Comment: Your code is running fine on my end and always calls `ENG_Request()` Not sure how yours reaches the last else block.

Comment: Try `LNG = ['ENG', 'DEU']` instead of placing them in a tuple

Comment: thanks. now it is working

Comment: Awesome, if you could accept my answer, that'd be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the function by using ():

```
ENG_Request()
```

Comment: sorry !! I forgot to add that in my code. but I am getting the error as print "NO More Languages". it is not calling any function

Comment: You do `LNG = ('ENG', 'DEU')` and then `if (LNG[0] == 'ENG'): print LNG[0]`. This should always be the case, given this code.

Comment: thanks. now it is working fine. but if I am getting the LNG as a parameter then if I want to compare that LNG is ENG then call some function, if LNG is DEU then call some other function

Comment: You better post a new question (since your current question is answered). (Don't forget to mark it answered :) )